# Iterating over a multidimensional array / dictionary and concatenating sub-elements in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to use Ansible to take an array of databases, with sub-elements for tables and then iterate through them to create a sed one-liner which can strip all trace of inserts to those tables from an SQL dump file.

The databases and tables will be defined as follows...

```
databases:
  - db1:
    - table1
    - table2
  - db2: 
    - table3
    - table4
    - table5
```

The commands I'd like Ansible to run would be as follows...

```
cat db1.sql | sed '/INSERT INTO `table1`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `table2`/d' > db1-out.sql
cat db2.sql | sed '/INSERT INTO `table3`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `table4`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `table5`/d' > db2-out.sql
```

I believe I should be able to do this with the shell module, using with_items, but I'm not quite sure how I would implode / concatenate the table names together.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @udondan for the solution, here is an example playbook which works with Ansible 1.9.4:

```
---
# Example playbook for Ansible 1.9.4
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    databases:
      - db1:
        - table1
        - table2
      - db2: 
        - table3
        - table4
        - table5

  tasks:

    - shell: "cat {{ item.keys() | first }}.sql | {{ item[item.keys() | first] | map(\"regex_replace\", \"^(.*)$\", \"sed '/INSERT INTO `\\\\1`/d'\") | join(\" | \") }} > {{ item.keys() | first }}-out.sql"
      with_items: databases
```

Unfortunately the regexp replace escaping seems to work differently in Ansible 2.0.0.2 so I had to change the \\\\1 (quadruple backslashes) to \\1 (double backslashes)

```
---
# Example playbook for Ansible 2.0.0.2
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    databases:
      - db1:
        - table1
        - table2
      - db2: 
        - table3
        - table4
        - table5

  tasks:

    - shell: "cat {{ item.keys() | first }}.sql | {{ item[item.keys() | first] | map(\"regex_replace\", \"^(.*)$\", \"sed '/INSERT INTO `\\1`/d'\") | join(\" | \") }} > {{ item.keys() | first }}-out.sql"
      with_items: databases
```

Comment: You only had to escape because you quoted the whole string. My task below was tested with Ansible 2.0.0.2 - But indeed, they changed something in Ansible 2 which affects escaping of backslashes.

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me on Ansible 1.9.4 without quoting the string. The output looked like this 'INSERT INTO `\u0001`/d'.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - shell: cat {{ item.keys() | first }}.sql | {{ item[item.keys() | first] | map("regex_replace", "^(.*)$", "sed '/INSERT INTO `\1`/d'") | join(" | ") }} > {{ item.keys() | first }}-out.sql
   with_items: databases
```

This task will execute the commands:

```
cat db1.sql | sed '/INSERT INTO `table1`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `table2`/d' > db1-out.sql
cat db2.sql | sed '/INSERT INTO `table3`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `table4`/d' | sed '/INSERT INTO `table5`/d' > db2-out.sql
```

[map](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) applies another filter to each element of the list. In this case [regex_replace](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters). [join](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#join) concatenates a sequence of strings into a single string. `.keys()` gets the keys of a python hash.

<sup>In case you had seen my previous answer... I first thought it's not possible to get to the data without knowing the name of the dict keys, but turns out you can actually use `keys()` right in the template. I did not expect that.</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to tweak escaping a bit to get it to work, but that does exactly what I wanted! Here's the escaped line that worked for me... `- shell: "cat {{ item.keys() | first }}.sql | {{ item[item.keys() | first] | map(\"regex_replace\", \"^(.*)$\", \"sed '/INSERT INTO \`\\\\1\`/d'\") | join(\" | \") }} > {{ item.keys() | first }}-out.sql"`